# Why does $\|x\|_q\leq\|x\|_p$ imply that $\ell_p\subset\ell_q$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, lp-spaces

> [image]

Could someone help explain why we get inclusion after the inequality involving norms at the end of the proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the proof showed that given an arbitrary element $x$ of $\ell_p$, we have that $x\in\ell_q$, which is the definition of inclusion

Comment: Might be helpful to add why this is a consequence of the fact that $|x|_q\le |x|_p.$ If the RHS is finite (i.e. $x\in l^p$), so must be the LHS (so $x\in l^q$).